# How to fix "amdgpu dkms failed for running kernel" when installing amd gpu drivers?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, gpu, amd-graphics, dkms

I am attempting to install the AMD gpu drivers for an RX 480 in Ubuntu 18.4.2. Whenever I run amdgpu-install or amdgpu-pro-install I get

> amdgpu dkms failed for running kernel.

[Link to make.log](https://gist.github.com/deef0000dragon1/3b725659fe94b9663f6fa0fe8a702323)

I should note that I do have NVIDIA drivers installed as well, as I am using an NVIDIA 1070ti for compute, however, the card is currently not physically in the system so that I can test the AMD card/drivers.

Answer (score 3):

It depends of which kernel version you're running. latest [amdgpu-pro drivers](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-rad-lin-18-50-unified) works fine with kernel 4.15.0-47-generic and dkms build success

Install working kernel with latest drivers

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-4.15.0-47-generic \
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-47-generic \
linux-headers-4.15.0-47-generic
```

reboot into linux-image-4.15.0-47-generic

Install latest driver from [https://amd.com](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-rad-lin-18-50-unified)

```
wget --referer support.amd.com https://drivers.amd.com/drivers/linux/amdgpu-pro-18.50-725072-ubuntu-18.04.tar.xz 
tar xf amdgpu-pro-18.50-725072-ubuntu-18.04.tar.xz
cd amdgpu-pro-18.50-725072-ubuntu-18.04
./amdgpu-pro-install
```

Then reboot and Voilà
Cheers

edit: update new kernel version

Comment: I'm getting the same failure on a fresh Kubuntu 18.04 install with kernel 4.18.0-16-generic from the 18.50-725072 drivers.

Comment: My issue is known: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109440 the recommendation is to wait for the 19.10 drivers or downgrade to kernel 4.15.

Comment: DKMS will simply not build with kernel > 4.15, that's why you need a 4.15 kernel to build them. By the way if you just need openCL stuff, you can install driver using `amdgpu-pro-install --no-dkms` and use any kernel version after 4.17

Comment: @Fractalyse I wish that were documented by AMD on the page that gives the instructions. Also, I am just trying it and I still see that it does attempt to build the module with DKMS ... that's rather odd. As if the failed previous installations somehow prevent me from using `--no-dkms` (although that's documented when invoking it with `--help`),

Comment: @0xC0000022L you should try amdgpu-pro-19.30-934563, i'm currently using with radeon vii, it's working great and DKMS built with mainline kernel (4.15.0-91-generic).
wget --referer support.amd.com https://drivers.amd.com/drivers/linux/amdgpu-pro-19.30-934563-ubuntu-18.04.tar.xz

Comment: Hmm, I assumed the `amdgpu-pro-19.50-1011208-ubuntu-18.04` would be working. And it did, but not before I hadn't installed the 4.15 kernel (the HWE kernel, a 5.3, did not work with whatever code AMD provides in these tarballs, i.e. DKMS fails).

Comment: AMD just released amdgpu-pro-20.10 on their website, and it is building both with 4.15 a 5.3 kernels